# Creating a static extension property for Kotlin with KotlinPoet

Tags: kotlinpoet

I am a complete newbie to using KotlinPoet.

I would like to programmatically generate the following code using KotlinPoet:

```
public val MyClass.Companion.classID: Long
  get() = 0x100
```

Unfortunately, after many attempts, I have not yet found a way to create that Companion Object of a class.

Maybe someone knows a possible solution, or can this not be realized with KotlinPoet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Companion` is simply a nested class, so you can create a `ClassName` representing the companion using [`ClassName.nestedClass()`](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-class-name/nested-class.html):

```kotlin
val myClass = ClassName(packageName = "", "MyClass")
val companion = myClass.nestedClass("Companion")
println(companion) // MyClass.Companion
```